# How can I access the text response from API. in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, dialogflow-es

I'm trying to access the textresponse that API.AI comes up with, in my swift app. But the .speech property is deppreciated and I've legit tried everything for the last 40 mins. Can someone please tell me how? Below is my code:

```
@IBAction func sendMessage(_ sender: Any) {
let request = ApiAI.shared().textRequest()

if let text = self.messageField.text, text != "" {
    request?.query = text
} else {
    return
}

request?.setMappedCompletionBlockSuccess({ (request, response) in
    let response = response as! AIResponse
    if let textResponse = response.result.fulfillment.speech {
        self.speechAndText(text: textResponse)
    }
}, failure: { (request, error) in
    print(error!)
})

ApiAI.shared().enqueue(request)
messageField.text = ""
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Found elsewhere in case anyone needs an answer to the same question:

```
let response = response as! AIResponse
if let msgs = response.result.fulfillment.messages {
  let resp = msgs [ 0 ] as NSDictionary
  print(resp.value(forKey: "speech") as! String)
}
```